# Completeness of Wasserstein space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, optimal-transport

In [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/278829/counter-example-to-the-completeness-of-the-wasserstein-metric) it is said that:

> On a complete, non necessarily separable metric space $E$, the set $P_r(E)$ of all Radon probability measures with the Wasserstein-Kantorovich metric $W_d$ is complete;

and that the above is a known fact. 
However I can't seem to find a published reference. Could someone please point me to one? I need in particular a reference of the result above where separability is *not* required.

Comment: In Villani's book on Optimal transport, it is Theorem 6.18. However it is proved for separable metric spaces.